# Call csc.exe in post build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I need to run the C# compiler `csc.exe` after building the project, but before launching it. It cannot be run "implicitly" as the C# files it needs to compile are generated dynamically, in a previous post build event. (The C# files are generated by running an external program against a JAR-file (Java); the `csc`-call is actually contained in a batchfile that is generated by the program. I would run this batchfile in a post-build event).
The problem is that when I try to call it, VS doesn't find it as it doesn't seem to be in `PATH`. Also, I can't find the `vcvarsall.bat` file (which presumably would add `csc.exe` to the path) and I cannot install the VS component that contains it as I'm working on a client's restricted machine.

But I can successfully run `csc` manually, by launching it inside the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015".

EDIT: For now using `CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` seems to work, but is there another way that doesn't use a hardcoded path to some BAT-file? Why doesn't VS let me use `csc`, when it uses it itself implicitly?

Comment: 1) It is interesting that some C# source files are only available in post build event. If you elaborate more, there might be a better option. 2) Visual Studio consumes MSBuild API, so it does not call csc directly. 3) You shouldn't rely on VsDevCmd either. 4) There are several compilers with .NET Framework you might use https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c and you can also detect MSBuild/csc by using vswhere, https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere

Comment: @LexLi The C# files are generated from Java code to enable calling it from C# (http://jni4net.com/). Implementation details in the Java code might change, so I have to call the generator every time. The generator writes some C# files and a build script (which would call the C# compiler to build the DLL). I guess a cleaner approach would be to include the C# files in a subproject and let them compile by VS. But that would mean creating dummy C# files and then the generator overwriting them. After the build I'd have to overwrite them with the dummies again so they don't change in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick solution, you can use the following command to execute the batch file independent from the installation directory of Visual Studio 2015:

```
call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

---

A probably better approach would be to write a separate *.csproj file that references the code files that are created by the external job and add that project in your solution and make it depend on the project that generates the source files.